# Is it safe to interrupt tomcat thread

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat

I am in a wierd situation. In my web-server (tomcat), on web request, I basically need to cancel a previous request. I have a reference to the thread that was executing the previous request. So I can directly interrupt that thread and the node will do the rest.

I know you are not suppose to interrupt the thread which you do not own. But is it safe to interrupt tomcat thread in this case? What can be the other way? Maintaining own thread pool is waste of resources and ovehead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maintaining your own thread pool is a waste of resource but it's also a gain in every other respect, like stability of your application server. So you need to decide what is more important: A few thousand bytes of memory and CPU cycles or a stable, reliable application.

The problem with interrupting another thread is that you usually can't know for sure where in the code that other thread is. You might want to use locking for this:

Thread A locks something while it's safe to interrupt, thread B checks the lock and if it can't get it, it interrupts A.

But what happens when A is just about to give up the lock, B checks the lock, A unlocks and starts with cleanup, B sends interrupt?

So you should really use your own thread pool.

Answer (score 1):

I would not do it. Not 100% sure why, but I think those threads come from Tomcat's own worker thread pool and killing them one-by-one  would/could eventually result in a non-responding Tomcat instance. (This is just a hypothesis).

I would argue that "maintaining own threadpool is waste of resources and overhead". I think it is a minor thing, threadpools are great guys, do no be afraid of them. I do not know the details of your application but I think if you measured the overhead by JConsole you could decide the point to do some optimization and it is not probable that the threadpool would be the bottleneck.

The best think I could suggest to you is a **complete redesign**: use short-returning HTTP requests to start long-running asynchronous operations in the background by submitting tasks to an `ExecutorService` or stuff. This way there is no need to harm Tomcat's own threads and the overall usability of your application could also be improved from a user/client perspective.

To sum up: I think it is not safe to do what you mentioned and one possible other way to do  what you want is described in the above paragraph.

Comment: No it doesn't happen (non-responding tomcat). Also I make sure that the interrupt status is cleared at teh end of the computation.

Comment: So you say that Tomcat starts new threads in its worker pool to replace interrupted ones? Thanks for the update.

Comment: Yes it does. But because I am clearing the interrupt status, tomcat is unaware of this in the end. And it is not closed